# Should EM algorithm's final imputed mean match the initial parameter?

Tags: r, data-imputation, expectation-maximization

I am running a manual EM (expectation-maximization) algorithm in r. My code is the following:

```
em.norm <- function(Y,mit,sit)
{Yobs <- Y[!is.na(Y)] #Extract the observed values
Ymis <- Y[is.na(Y)] #Extract the missing values
n <- length(c(Yobs,Ymis)) #Length of total observations
r <- length(Yobs) #length of available observations

#Initial values
mut <- mit
sit <- sit

#Define log-likelihood function
ll = function(Y,mu,sigma2,n)
{
-0.5*n*log(2*pi*sigma2) - 0.5*sum((Y-mu)^2)/sigma2
}

#compute log-likelihood for initial values
#and ignoring missing data mechanism

lltm1 <- ll(Yobs,mut,sit,n)
repeat{
  
#E-step
EY <- sum(Yobs) + (n-r)*mut
EY2 <- sum(Yobs^2) + (n-r)*(mut^2 + sit)
#M-step
mut1 <- EY/n
sit1 <- EY2/n - mut1^2

#update parameter values

mut <- mut1
sit <- sit1

#Compute log-likelihood using current estimates
#and ignoring missing data 

llt <- ll(Yobs,mut,sit,n)

#Print current parameter values
cat(mut,sit,llt,"\n")

#Stop if converged 
if (abs(lltm1 - llt) < 0.001) break
lltm1 <- llt
}

#fill in missing values with new mu #

return(c(mut,sit))

}


set.seed(1234)
x <- data$xvar

xobs <- x[!is.na(x)]
xmis <- x[is.na(x)]
r <- length(xobs)
mit <- mean(xobs)
sit <- var(xobs)*(r-1)/r
em.norm(x,mit,sit)

em.norm(x,mit = mit, sit = sit)
```

I believe this code works, however, the final value of the completed data's mean is identical to the initial value of the mean. Conversely, the imputed variance is similar, but not identical to the initial variance.

This doesn't seem right to me. Should the imputed mean be the same as the initial mean, or did I mess up something in my code? If I have messed this code up, how are EM updates supposed to correctly fill in missingness and reestimate parameters?

Essentially, I am asking how the EM algorithm is used to fill in missing data, and what components of the data/algorithm are used to estimate the missing values.